# IdexedDB - Firefox 14 & Chrome 21

Tags: html, indexeddb

Ive been using [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB) code to make use of the indexedDB api. Works fine in FF 14. But in Chrome (v.21), im getting some errors. At the moment im having trouble with my createObjectStore command:

```
db.createObjectStore(objectStoreName, { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true });
```

Is it because Chrome is using a different spec than FF? Does some methods still differ?

Thanks

```
this.init = function (successCallback) {

        var openRequest = indexedDB.open(dbName);

        openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function (e) {

            db = e.target.result;

            if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains(objectStoreName)) {
                console.log('Create objectstore');
                db.createObjectStore(objectStoreName, { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true });
            }

            successCallback(e);

        };

        openRequest.onsuccess = function (e) {

            db = e.target.result;

            db.onerror = function (event) {
                console.log("Database error: " + event.target.errorCode);
            };

            successCallback(e);

        };

    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the error you get?

Difference between FF and chrome is that FF uses the onupgradeneeded callback and chrome the setVersion method to change the database structure

```
var req = indexedDB.open("name");
req.onsuccess = function(e){
    var db = req.result.db;
    var upgradereq = db.setVersion("1")
    upgradereq.onsuccess = function(event){
       upgradereq.result.db.createObjectStore("objectStoreName");
    }
}
```

Comment: `Uncaught Error: InvalidStateError: DOM IDBDatabase Exception 11`. Where should i create new objectstores in Chrome? In "Setversion"?

Comment: btw: http://greenido.wordpress.com/2012/05/15/indexeddb-changes-setversion-is-out/

Comment: I can tell you from my own experience that chromium still uses the setVersion method. I have an old blogpost (http://www.kristofdegrave.be/2011/10/indexed-db-defining-database-structure.html) on how to work with the setVersion. Can you show me some more code in where you call the createObjectStore method?

Comment: Updated my question with code. I always end up in onsuccess, and i get an error when i try to create the objectstore

Comment: Create or when you open the object store? If you want to check if chrome enters the onupgradeneeded event, you can add an alert into it. This way you will know if that callback get called.

Comment: btw I should advice you to make use of the result object on the request object instead of the event args you receive. For the onupgradeneeded event, the request.result keeps the version_change transaction you need to work on. On that you can call the db attribute to get the database object where you can call the createObjectStore method

Comment: There is no difference between what you have posted and what im doing. THe objectstore cant be created in the db

Comment: There's a polyfill for chrome here: https://gist.github.com/3361666. Save that locally, include it in your page and chrome should work the same way as firefox.

Comment: Thanks but didnt help. If you could show me a sample coude that manages to create an object store in the latest version of chrome it would be much appreciated. Im still getting ` Uncaught Error: InvalidStateError: DOM IDBDatabase Exception 11 `

Comment: Try the following code I edited in my original post. This is the way chrome works.

Comment: Thanks a lot, seems to be working. I suppose the blogpost i posted is incorrect then? Because this is the old/deprecated way according to that.

Comment: I think so. Even in version 23 (chrome canary) it is still the setVersion. So I think it won't change in the near future.

Comment: Next week's chrome canary will support both setVersion and upgradeneeded.